# XPath Parsing Specific Nodes

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath

I am needing to get the 'ItemKey="X"' value by an index for those matching '"Ref Location="C1"'  AND '"EventData ID="W12"'. If you notice, all four have "Ref Location="C1" but only the last 3 have '"EventData ID="W12"'

```
<Object>
<Level1>
    <Level2>
        <Ref Location="C1"/>
        <EventData ID="W6" EventKey="1">
            <FormData ID="NL">
                <ItemData ItemID="LINE" ItemKey="1">...</ItemData>
            </FormData>
        </EventData>
    </Level2>
</Level1>
<Level1>
    <Level2>
        <Ref Location="C1"/>
        <EventData ID="W12" EventKey="1">
            <FormData ID="NL">
                <ItemData ItemID="LINE" ItemKey="1">...</ItemData>
            </FormData>
        </EventData>
    </Level2>
</Level1>
<Level1>
    <Level2>
        <Ref Location="C1"/>
        <EventData ID="W12" EventKey="1">
            <FormData ID="NL">
                <ItemData ItemID="LINE" ItemKey="2">...</ItemData>
            </FormData>
        </EventData>
    </Level2>
</Level1>
<Level1>
    <Level2>
        <Ref Location="C1"/>
        <EventData ID="W12" EventKey="1">
            <FormData ID="NL">
                <ItemData ItemID="LINE" ItemKey="3">...</ItemData>
            </FormData>
        </EventData>
    </Level2>
</Level1>
```

Currently I have

```
(/Object/Level1/Level2/Ref[@Location='C1'])[2]/../EventData[@ID='W12']/FormData/ItemData/@ItemKey
```

Where X is the index but it gets ItemKey="X" for all the "C1" nodes. I need to get the ItemKey="X" for only the ID="W12" nodes.

Desired results when the path has this for '[X]'

```
[1] -> ItemKey="1"    // ID = "W12"
[2] -> ItemKey="2"    // ID = "W12"
[3] -> ItemKey="3"    // ID = "W12"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
//ItemData[preceding::Ref[1][@Location="C1"][following-sibling::EventData[@ID="W12"]]]/@ItemKey
```

Output : 3 values :

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks but I ran that here and got "no match" https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: I fixed my "currently I have" line. And also, I jut need the value of "ItemKey" as shown on my existing path.

Comment: OK. I've edited my post. Just add `/@ItemKey` at the end of the expression. http://xpather.com/QNX9VXCf

Comment: Well it didn't work before that on the freeformatter so that wouldn't work either.

Comment: It definitely works. https://framapic.org/1NEJMLp9qfZL/sIV3UWYAUPXL.PNG Your XPath returns one result. It was supposed to be 3 isn'it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that moving the index field farther down the path worked.

```
(/Object/Level1/Level2/Ref[@Location='C1']/../EventData[@ID='W12'])[1]/FormData/ItemData/@ItemKey
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify a Level2 element which contains a particular Ref element, use `[]`:

```
/Level2[Ref[@Location='C1']]
```

So your XPath becomes:

```
"/Object/Level1/Level2[Ref[@Location='C1']]" +
"/EventData[@ID='W12']/FormData/ItemData/@ItemKey"
```